# How do i get a user pfp in discord.py

Tags: python, discord

This is a snippet code from my bot that is meant to get mine or a users pfp and post it in the discord channel. For some reason, it does nothing when I type !avatar in discord. I have all the correct imports and there is no syntax error when I run it. I'm using repl.it I'm that might be the problem as I have absolutely no idea why this doesn't work.

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "t!")


@client.command
async def avatar(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.author
    
    icon_url = member.avatar_url 
 
    avatarEmbed = discord.Embed(title = f"{member.name}\'s Avatar", color = 0xFFA500)
 
    avatarEmbed.set_image(url = f"{icon_url}")
 
    avatarEmbed.timestamp = ctx.message.created_at 
 
    await ctx.send(embed = avatarEmbed)
```

Comment: It's looking correct

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm so confused I have even tried running the bot on a different server but it has the same result of no response not even in the console.

Comment: Try printing it on console

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Per the attempt to answer, it seems that this is simply a typo - you have specified `t!` as your command prefix, but `!avatar` (rather than `t!avatar`) as your attempt to run the command. As an aside, please note that when using triple backticks to format your code, they must be on a line by themselves at the bottom (on the top, you can write the name of the language you are using as a hint for syntax colouring; you should not have the first line of your code there). See the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for details.

Answer (score -1):

The command looks good for the most part. There are a few things I did notice, however.

First, there seem to be three backticks at the end of your message; these may have created a syntax error if they are present in your code. (If they were only used for pasting code, then that's perfectly fine.)

Second, you never closed your `if`-loop. Although this can be okay, it's good practice to close it with an `else`-statement, which should include the embed code. Here's what I made and tested (it worked fine):

```
@client.command(name= "embav", help="Send an embed of a member's avatar!")
async def avatar(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.author
        return #this just makes the code exit the loop
    else:
        icon_url = member.avatar_url
        avatarEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f"{member.name}\'s Avatar", color=0xFFA500)
        avatarEmbed.set_image(url=f"{icon_url}")
        avatarEmbed.timestamp = ctx.message.created_at
        await ctx.send(embed=avatarEmbed)
```

Third, you said:

> For some reason, it does nothing when I type !avatar in discord. I have all the correct imports and there is no syntax error when I run it.

But in the code, you specified a prefix of `t!`. If you just made a typo when asking, that's also fine.

Finally, if none of these help out, then it may be a repl.it problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. If you think the problem is some simple oversight (like trying to use the command incorrectly, rather than an actual problem in the code), then you should *not try to answer the question, as there is no question* - instead, vote to close it as "not reproducible or caused by a typo" (under "community-specific reasons"). The backticks are definitely an issue with posting the code, so I'll fix that.

Comment: What you are saying about coding style is a) off topic (try https://codereview.stackexchange.com if you are interested in advising on that - except insofar as it makes the problem easier to solve) and b) incorrect (an `if` statement is **not a loop**; there is definitely not any "good practice" rule to include an `else` if it isn't needed; and you change the behaviour of the code (it *should* produce an embed even when `member == None`, rather than bailing out - that's the *point* of assigning `member = ctx.author`).

Comment: Finally, because this is not a discussion forum, it is generally considered inappropriate to include chatty language in answers. If you need to refer to the OP to write your answer, simple blockquotes (see the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) are sufficient.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I'll keep this in mind.